# jQuery Animation Sequencing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have recreated in jsFiddle roughly what I currently have on my website. I would like to turn the click functionality into a time-based animation starting with the first div (image in my case) being "selected". After a couple seconds, say 2000 ms, it should animate back up 10px to the default state and the next div should animate down 10px to the "selected" state where it pauses for 2000 ms. I wish to continue this until all elements have been animated this way and then repeat the animation process indefinitely by returning the first div to the "selected" state when the last div animation is complete. I have been trying and trying to figure it out on my own but I cannot seem to get the delays set correctly.

Here is the demo of current functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/uFPtw/5 and the js below:

```
var prevLeft = 0;
var zInd = $('#projects div').length + 1;
$('#projects div').each(function() {
    prevLeft = prevLeft + 40;
    zInd = zInd - 1;
    $(this).css({
        'left': (prevLeft-40)+'px',
        'z-index': zInd
    });
});
$('#projects div').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css({
        'z-index': $('#projects div').length,
        'box-shadow': '0 0 20px #000',
        'cursor': 'default'
    }).animate({
        'top': '+10px'
    }, 200);
    if ( $('#projects div').css('top') != '0' ) {
        $(this).siblings('div').css({
            'box-shadow': '0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
            'cursor': 'pointer'
        }).animate({
            'top': '0'
        }, 200);
    }
    zInd1 = 4;
    $(this).prevAll().each(function() {
        zInd1 = zInd1 - 1;
        $(this).css({
            'z-index': zInd1
        });
    });
    $(this).nextAll().each(function() {
        zInd1 = zInd1 - 1;
        $(this).css({
            'z-index': zInd1
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you first capture the total number of div`s(in your case as of now) , then when  a click event is triggered or your automated function starts, you can check if you have reached the last div, based on which you can revert back to first div and call the target function again .

Comment: tenub, you are actually taking up all the div`s at once and doing the operation, but i think u can do the same functionality by taking single div at a time, i mean reduce the scope to single item , this would help u achieve your goal :)

Comment: i guess you will need this filter too, to select those wich are not animated   $(this).filter(':not(:animated)')

Comment: I'm looking to replace the click functionality completely with a time-based animation. I just can't figure out how to do it. I'm not looking to have both at once.

Comment: tenub,then u can add that(currently added within click event) complete functionality to a new function and call it on periodic basis.like i said earlier, you can add a check to see if its last div and go to first div and repeat the process ,like recursive call :)